# Need to optimize simple SELECT query for InnoDB table with 2million rows

Tags: mysql, innodb, optimization, myisam, select

I'd like to make this query the fastest possible, since it's called really often.

```
SELECT login_events.id 
FROM login_events 
WHERE (
  DATE(created_at) >= DATE(CURRENT_DATE) 
  AND person_id = 1
) 
LIMIT 1
```

It's running on a 157.7mb InnoDB table (says navicat), with ~2million rows and indexed on [created_at, person_id].

Using EXPLAIN I see it's using the index, but it says "Using where; Using index;". What can I do to make this the fastest possible? Would switching to MyISAM gain me anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, what you need to focus on are the three fields in the query

- id
- created_at
- person_id

The index you have `(created_at,person_id)` will make the query do an index scan across all the days of `created_at` after `CURRENT_DATE` looking for the `person_id`.

## **SUGGESTION #1** : You will definitely need a different index

## MyISAM

If `login_events` is MyISAM, this is the index you need

```
ALTER TABLE login_events ADD INDEX person_date_ndx (person_id,created_at,id);
```

This changes the query because the query will look for the specific `person_id` and scan all days for `person_id` 1 only. The reason `id` is included in the index ? The query will retrieve the `id` from the index only file rather than the table. That way, all 3 fields are retrieved from the index file instead of 2 fields from the index and 1 from the table.

## InnoDB

If `login_events` is InnoDB, this is the index you need

```
ALTER TABLE login_events ADD INDEX person_date_ndx (person_id,created_at);
```

The reason I recommend this is the same, but you do not need to include `id`. Why? [All index pages include an index point back to the clustered index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-index-types.html) so retrieval of an index will intrinsically access the row anyway, thus accessing id. Adding `id` to the index would simply be redundant.

## **SUGGESTION #2** : Change the Date Comparison

From the expression

```
DATE(created_at) >= DATE(CURRENT_DATE)
```

I can tell that `created_at` is either `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`.

The expression forces the query to convert every row's DATETIME value of `created_on` into a DATE.

Therefore, instead of

```
SELECT login_events.id 
FROM login_events 
WHERE (
  DATE(created_at) >= DATE(CURRENT_DATE) 
  AND person_id = 1
) 
LIMIT 1
```

express the date comparison as a time comparison starting from midnight of today

```
SELECT login_events.id 
FROM login_events 
WHERE (
  created_at >= (DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 0 SECOND)
  AND person_id = 1
) 
LIMIT 1
```

## CAVEAT

Since the table is so small, either storage engine would be fine. I would give the edge to MyISAM.

## Give it a Try !!!

Comment: I really appreciate the extended answer Rolando. The bit about date / time comparisons makes a ton of sense, yet that's something I wouldn't have considered.

Thank you!